# How can i add Google adsense betwen paragraph in codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, adsense

i need yourhelp please to add Adsense code betwen posts content like in wordpress
my code to show post conetent is like this

```
<div class="post-text">
 <?php echo $post->content; ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop with a condition like if you want to show your ads after every 7 post so your code would like this.

```
    foreach($posts as $key => $post)
    {
       if($key%7 ==0)
       {
        echo 'your adsense code';
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank y very much but  this code is betwen posts, what i need is betwen paragraphs in post,    just insert one ads in middle of content post

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$str="Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor";

    $str_arr=explode(' ',$str); // use your own delimiter which can be </br> or </p>
    $words_count=count($str_arr);
    $middlecount=($words_count/2);
    $ads_text='Test Demo Test Test Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo Test';
    $str_arr[$middlecount]= $ads_text.'<br>'.$str_arr[$middlecount];

    $final_text=implode(' ',$str_arr);
    echo $final_text;
```

This is a test example. Minor tweaks will be required for your scenario.

YOu can aslo try one more way which is you using wordpress so the user will add the content from admin panel then you ask user to use a predefined tag eg ADSENSE in the content in editor(where he want to show the ad).

Now in frontend you can simply do something like this :

```
$post_content=$post->content;
echo str_replace('ADSENSE',$ads_text,$post_content); // will require some tweaks as per requirement
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score -1):

$str="Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor Lorem Ipsum Test Dolor";

```
$str_arr=explode(' ',$str); // use your own delimiter which can be </br> or </p>
$words_count=count($str_arr);
$middlecount=($words_count/2);
$ads_text='Test Demo Test Test Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo TestTest Demo Test';
$str_arr[$middlecount]= $ads_text.'<br>'.$str_arr[$middlecount];

$final_text=implode(' ',$str_arr);
echo $final_text;
```